# a question on improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions, improper-integrals

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ converges. I read that there exists necessarly $a>0$ such that $\int_{0}^{a}tf(t)dt=a^2f(a)$
It seems natural to study the function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x tf(t)dt$ but things still jot clear to me.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Two questions: $\mathbb{R}^+$ does not include $0$ for you, does it? And does the integral of $f$ converge in the sense of Lebesgue or improper Riemann integrals?

Comment: @user23571113 Yes it does include 0 and the existence is in the sense of improper Riemann integrals

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is positive then the exercise can be proved in the following way.

Denote your function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x tf(t)\,dt$ by $g$.

First of all, notice that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x) = tf(t)\big|_{t = 0} = 0$.

Secondly, let us show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = 0$. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $N$ be such that $\int_N^{\infty}f(t) < \varepsilon$. Then we have
$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x tf(t)\,dt}{x} = \limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^N tf(t)\,dt + \int_N^x tf(t)\,dt}{x} \le \limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^N tf(t)\,dt + x\int_N^{\infty} tf(t)\,dt}{x}\le \varepsilon.
$$

Therefore, By Rolle's theorem there exists $a > 0$ such that $g'(a) = 0$. It remains to notice that $$ g'(a) = \left(\frac{\int_0^a tf(t)\,dt}{a}\right)' = \frac{a^2f(a) - \int_0^a tf(t)\,dt}{a^2}.$$

UPD. For a non necessarily positive $f$ one can integrate by parts to notice that
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x tf(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{x}\left[tF(t)\big|_0^x - \int_0^x F(t)\,dt\right] = \frac{1}{x}\left[xF(x) - \int_0^x F(t)\,dt\right] = {\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\left[ F(x) - F(t)\right]\,dt,}
$$
where $F$ is antiderivative of $f$.

Now $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0$ can be proved using the same idea as in the positive case.

Comment: Nice idea to use the Rolle theorem  ! (+). I think the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=0$ can be proved for $f$ not necessarily positive, applying the formula $$g(x)={1\over x}\int\limits_0^x[F(x)-F(t)]\,dt$$ where $$F(x)=\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dt$$

Comment: Oh! It really does help, thank you!

Comment: If you like you can include that in your nice solution. The formula is proved by applying integration by parts to $\int tf(t)\,dt$

Comment: Not $\limsup g(x)$ but $\lim g(x)$